# ¿Como eliminar valores repetidos de una columna en HQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Tengo una consulta con dos tablas de las que quiero traer todos los campos, pero uno de las columnas tiene repetidos los valores, quiero eliminar los que tengo repetidos.

Mi consulta actualmente está de esta manera

```
 @Query("select distinct t1 from Tabla1 inner join t1.tabla2 t2 where t2.id=:id ORDER BY t1.descripcion
```

pero me repite los valores de la columna descripción. He probado también a hacerlo de esta forma:

```
 @Query("select distinct(t1.descripcion) from Tabla1 inner join t1.tabla2 t2 where t2.id=:id ORDER BY t1.descripcion
```

Y no me repite los valores de la columna descripción, pero no consigo traer todos los datos. Es necesario que traiga todos los datos porque tengo que hacer operaciones distintas operaciones.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Quieres eliminar el registro o solo el campo?

Comment: quiero que en la select no me muestre los valores repetidos, es decir el registro repetido

Comment: ¿Y si dos registros tienen ese campo identico, como se decide cual es el repetido?

Comment: Lo que tenemos en la select es un id único y un nombre, los ids son únicos pero por ejemplo en la consulta tenemos una misma descripción n veces, nos da igual cual sea el que se muestre con tal de que sea uno solo, ya que el valor es el mismo (ejemplo: 1. casa, 2. casa, 3.hotel) en este caso solo queremos eliminar una casa, nos da igual cual sea. No la eliminamos de BD si no de la select que muestra los datos

Comment: Agrupa por el campo descipcion y quedate con el valor mas bajo del id. SELECT MIN(id), descripcion FROM ....... GROUP BY descripcion.

Comment: Igual que la respuesta que @JasRockr está también es una opción válida que sirvió adaptando la consulta a hql, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, considerando tu ejemplo y teniendo en cuenta el resultado que quieres obtener una buena opción puede ser la que menciona JDEV y hacer un GROUP BY por la descripcion; por otro lado también puedes hacer un ROW_NUMBER partiendo por el campo descripción (que es el repetido) y ordenado por el mismo campo para mostrar al final solo aquellos registros ubicados en la posición número uno (1), espero haberme hecho entender sería algo más o menos así:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.description ORDER BY T1.descripcion DESC) AS Rank
T2.id, 
T1.description
FROM
Tabla1 AS T1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE
Rank = 1
```

El resultado sin el where es algo como esto y al aplicar el where solo se mostrarían los registros donde el valor del Rank es igual a '1'

```
|RANK|ID|DESCRIPTION|
|1|012|CASA|
|2|013|CASA|
|1|014|HOTEL|
|1|015|OFICINA|
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Feliz día..

Comment: Ha funcionado aunque el código para mi consulta en hql queda distinto, pero la funcionalidad es similar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Con mucho gusto, tienes razón, imaginé que cambiaría igual me parece genial que hayas comprendido el concepto y lo hayas adaptado a tu necesidad.